# Java mail TLS authentcation

Tags: java, email, ssl, smtp, jakarta-mail

I am trying to get a grasp on the fundamentals of Java Mail API and TLS. I have the following scenario:

There is an STMP server that uses TLS & SSL. If I log on to this server with some client, I can send authenticated &verified e-mails without any problems.

Then I try to run a web server on a different machine, that sends mail using the previously mentioned SMTP server. I still want to send TLS & SSL emails, however no matter how I configure the startup properties I get the following well known error:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
```

I found a lot of people having similar issues, however my question is this:

Considering the previuosly described scenario, do I have to get some kind of certificate to the web server (possible somewhere in the JRE), or should it just work fine since the mail server already has that certificate & authentication mechanizm running. Shouldn't it be possible to just use the certificate of the SMTP server? Anyway, if I have to install the certificate to the machine that uses the STMP server how can I get that certificate?

I'm pretty new to JavaMail API and I have seen lots of articles about this but I could not find the answer black & white for my question.

Comment: I'm getting the same problem(Please see my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31179399/how-to-validate-smtp-servers-ssl-tls-certificate-using-java-mail-api).  I'm trying to understand how you managed to get the ssl/tls  certificate of SMTP server programmatically and validated it? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your client (that is in your case the one running on the webserver) needs to verify the SSL certificate of the mail server. It seems that your java truststore doesn't contain that certificate.

So you either need to put that certificate into the default truststore of your JRE (what I wouldn't recommend) or define a different truststore for your application (that of course needs to contain the mail servers certificate). To do that set this VM parameter: `Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=<path-to-truststore>`

Edit: Ah I missed some part of your question.
To get the certificate of the mail server use something like openssl. See for example:
https://serverfault.com/questions/139728/how-to-download-ssl-certificate-from-a-website

Comment: @user1960804 If the answer solves your problem, please click the accept button

Comment: I will, I need to test it first, in a few hours no worries.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is in the [JavaMail FAQ](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javamail/faq/index.html#installcert).

Quoted text from the linked site:

> Q: When connecting to my mail server over SSL I get an exception like "unable to find valid certification path to requested target".
>
> A: Your server is probably using a test certificate or self-signed certificate instead of a certificate signed by a commercial Certificate Authority. You'll need to install the server's certificate into your trust store. The InstallCert program will help.
>
> Alternatively, you can set the "mail.protocol.ssl.trust" property to the host name of your mail server. See the javadocs for the protocol provider packages for details.
>
> Other common causes of this problem are:
>
> - There's a firewall or anti-virus program intercepting your request.
> - There's something wrong in your JDK installation preventing it from finding the certificates for the trusted certificate authorities.
> - You're running in an application server that has overridden the JDK's list of trusted certificate authorities.